# I cannot edit SharePoint 2013 custom page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, publishing-page

I have created a custom page and it is deployed as globally.I have created a custom web part then exported the custom web part and added the XML reference in page layout `Element.XML` file.

If I go to edit page the page is not responding, edit menu is not showing. I can't delete the web part from the page. The web part contains the angular js and bootstrap files.
Is it possible to work normally for edit page? Please suggest any idea.

Comment: Have you tired opening the page in SharePoint designer?

Comment: no . i am not tried in designer.

Comment: Please try doing same may be you can change something from their or remove xsl reference to make your page normal again.

Comment: ya , i have solved this problem .its an style issue.thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Open your page which is having error and add
**?Contents=1** to the end of the page’s URL. If the URL already has a **“?”** then add this instead to the end of the URL:
**&Contents=1**

> **Example:**
>
> https://*YourWebApplication*/sites/*SiteName*/Pages/*PageName*.aspx?contents=1

Now you can delete the WebPart